# Is Drop Shadow on Div Boxes with CSS Possible?

Tags: css

What's the easiest way to create drop shadows around div boxes?   A print media designer sent me this example design:

http://glacialsummit.com/shadow.jpg

As you can see, the drop shadow seems to "glow" around the div box.  Is this easy to re-create with CSS? Or should I tell the designer it's impractical to create this?

Comment: you need CSS3 which is only supported by modern browsers. Let's hope if there are other options :)

Comment: @sAc: Actually, it's even possible in IE6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes, it is possible](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/), even in IE6.

Answer (score 2):

[It is possible with CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/). But the browsers still use their own CSS property names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with CSS3. Here is the sample:

```
selector {
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #666;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #666;
}
```

Would work in most of major browsers except IE.

Here is the explain:

```
selector {
  box-shadow: x-coordinate y-coordinate blur-radius color;
}
```

Cheers.